# Can strace tell me if a syscall is blocked?

Tags: linux, strace

I want to know

- if there was a context switch between making that call and getting the result
- If the call response is still pending

Comment: `if there was a context switch between making that call and getting the result` - there definitely was, providing that syscalls are implemented using architecture-specific exception instruction for example SVC on ARM

Comment: If the syscall is blocked then there will be no progress and strace will show that as the last call with nothing after it. Not sure if that is what you mean.